# C# plugin error in SonarQube

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am seeing below error logs while analysing my code in SonarQube.

SonarQube Version 5.1.1 - LGPL V3

sonar-csharp-plugin-4.5.jar

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.1

MSBuild 12.0

I cannot upgrade my Sonarqube version to latest one due to project dependencies.Changed C# plugin from 4.5 jar to 5.1 jar but still no luck. Please suggest.

Error Logs-

```
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.1
Default properties file was found at C:\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SonarQube_Scanner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SonarQube_Scanner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
Checking for updates...
Could not connect to the SonarQube server. Check the url is correct and that the server is available. Url: http://example-software.com/
Failed to update the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild binaries. Check the server url, verify that the C# plugin is correctly installed on the SonarQube server and that the SonarQube server has been restarted.
Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
Set build name.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear:

> Could not connect to the SonarQube server. Check the url is correct and that the server is available. Url: http://example-software.com/

You need to check your `sonar.host` value and make sure it's correct. If it is, then you need to talk to the network people to make sure that your analysis machine can talk to your SonarQube server.